# how to print a string to UITextField in xcode ios

Tags: ios, uitextfield, xcode7

I m having a mobile number, which is saved in **NSString** variable in the program, which i want to display in a **UITextField** when the user gets into the window of user details in my ios app. I also want to disable the editing of the phone number. how can i do that? i m using xcode 7.4.2

Comment: can you show the tried code

Comment: You can use print function for print textFieldData print(usertextfiledname.text) and disable textField yourtextFileldname.userInterface = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initially check your String Contains value or not and do like

```
yourMobileNumberTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = true;
if (yourString.length > 0)
{
 yourMobileNumberTextfield.text = yourString;
 yourMobileNumberTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = false;
 }
```

**Swift**

```
yourMobileNumberTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = true
if yourString.length > 0 {
yourMobileNumberTextfield.text = yourString
yourMobileNumberTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

**update**

for hold the previous value in your app then go for `NSUserDefault`,

**Step-1**

when your OTP verification is success then save the Current Mobile Number in `UserDefaults`

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourMobileNumberTextfield.text forKey:@"Mobile"];
```

**Step-2**

if second Time user comes on the page where you need call like

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"Mobile"];

yourMobileNumberTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = true;
if (savedValue.length > 0)
{
 yourMobileNumberTextfield.text = savedValue;
 yourMobileNumberTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = false;
 }
```

**Swift**

**Save**

```
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(yourMobileNumberTextfield.text, forKey: "Mobile")
```

**Retrieve**

```
  let savedValue =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Mobile")!
yourMobileNumberTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = true
if savedValue.length > 0 {
yourMobileNumberTextfield.text = savedValue
yourMobileNumberTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: the first line inside the if loop is showing warning, that is: yourMobileNumberTextfield.text = yourString; is showing warning that "incompatible pointer types assigning to NSString *_Nullable from 'UITextField'"

Comment: @SHAHALNS - in this place `yourMobileNumberTextfield` assign your `Mobilenumbertextfieldname` and in this place `yourString` assign your mobilenumber value already you added in previously

Comment: @SHAHALNS - can you update the question with your answer

Comment: if(_MobileNumber.length>0) {  _PhoneNumber.text = _MobileNumber;  _PhoneNumber.userInterfaceEnabled=false; }

Comment: @SHAHALNS - not like if(_mobileNumber.length>0)  do like if(_mobileNumber.text.length>0)

Comment: @SHAHALNS - can you attach your project or current class in in your question

Comment: @SHAHALNS - ok when you have a chance update your question we will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Get mobile no into text field

```
NSString *strMobileNo = @"036467345672";  //Give your no here
yourTextFieldName.text = strMobileNo;
   //OR
yourTextFieldName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"036467345672"];
   //OR
yourTextFieldName.text = @"036467345672";
```

Disable the textField Edit

```
yourTextFieldName.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: the first line inside the if loop is showing warning, that is: yourMobileNumberTextfield.text = yourString; is showing warning that "incompatible pointer types assigning to NSString *_Nullable from 'UITextField'"

Comment: Give your your text field and string name and how do you get the mobile no to string?

Comment: What is textField name here?

Comment: yourString means what?

Answer (score 0):

if the UITextField name is "textField" and NSString variable u having was "phone".

```
textField.text=phone;
textField.enabled=true;
```

I will prefer using UILabel instead,If you need these two things to be done. It is by default cannot be edited.

Comment: the first line inside the if loop is showing warning, that is: yourMobileNumberTextfield.text = yourString; is showing warning that "incompatible pointer types assigning to NSString *_Nullable from 'UITextField'"

Comment: try '[self textField]=phone;' or '_textField.text=phone;'

Comment: @SHAHAL check whether the variable phone is NSString type